# Merging vector layers in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, merge, vector-layer

I am facing problem merging vector layers (point layer,and buffer layer)

[image: Prblem while merging multiplr vector layers]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to merge polygon layer (Buffer layer) with the point layer, which is impossible because the geometry of both layers are different. The merge tool works only with the same geometry not with mixed geometries.

Comment: No.I am merging layer having same geometry.

Comment: You said buffer layer and usually buffers are polygons, and looking at your map the circles around the points are polygons. Otherwise your question is not clear, and you need to add more information about the type of layers, and any necessary information.

Comment: You can merge layers with MMQGIS plugin,  What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to transfer attributes from a point layer to a polygon (buffer) layer, you should use Join Attributes By Location instead of Merge.

If there are several points within each buffer polygon, you can also get the sum, mean, median etc from all numeric columns in the points with the Attribute Summary function in the Join Attributes dialog. Just set it to "Take summary of intersecting features."